# Word for: "dislike of people that has same gender as speaker"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a word for "disliking people of same gender"? I.e. man that dislikes men in general (but not women), or woman that dislikes women in general (but not men)?

There's "misanthropy", but it means "dislike of humans in general", and "misogyny"/"misandry" do not satisfy "same gender" requirement. Is there a specific word for that?

Comment: Because misogyny and misandry (misogynous/misandrous) exist, I'd be interested to see a sentence with your word represented as a blank and the only possibility.

Comment: Pity that *homophobe* is already taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Misogyny/Misandry can absolutely satisfy the 'same gender' requirement if applied appropriately. If you're looking for a word that can be applied across the board for what feminists call 'internalized misogyny', though, I don't think there is one.

Comment: "can absolutely satisfy" Umm... That's not quite it - I've been looking for specific word that precisely describes dislike of people that belong to same gender. I'm not sure if there IS such a word, of course...

Comment: Right, you're looking for a gender-neutral term to describe the phenomenon only when it's applied reflexively? Pretty sure that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

It may not yet have much currency, but [**cisgenderphobic**](http://zh-cn.facebook.com/events/338559899541678/?ref=nf) is already out there!

The word is formed by extrapolation from, for example, [cisatlantic](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=cisatlantic&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=MYjjT43CN4e18QOb0OjUDg&ved=0CGEQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1821ba54f6c138b6&biw=1538&bih=799) *(on the same side of the Atlantic as the speaker)*, and [cisalpine](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&tbs=dfn:1&sclient=psy-ab&q=cisalpine&oq=cisalpine&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.66894.69670.2.70029.12.12.0.0.0.0.110.934.11j1.12.0...0.0.d4-wRxIg9fw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=102a441a6c9c3d1c&biw=1538&bih=799) *(on the southern side of the Alps)*.

As can be inferred from the definition of *cisalpine*, the *cis-* prefix already carries overtones of prejudice/bigotry - the assumption being that anyone living *north* of the Alps would be too ignorant to use such erudite terminology, so it's okay to define *this side of the Alps* as "south".

Comment: Is it OK to use `-phobic` for "dislike of" as well as "fear of"? Fearing something and disliking something are not the same at all.

Comment: Due to current usage of *cisgender*, my first-blush understanding of that term would be of indicating being afraid of / hating people whose gender identity matches their biological sex expression.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: It's kinda annoying, but the term "homophobia" has so thoroughly embedded that sort of usage in the culture that we may as well roll with it.  The general idea is that hate proceeds from fear, like Yoda says.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Consider, for example, [hydrophobic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hydrophobic) *- repelling, tending not to combine with, or incapable of dissolving in water*. I think you're attaching preconceived associations for words like *"arachnophobia"* (fear of spiders) to assign a fear/dislike distinction that the *-phobia* suffix doesn't actually carry in and of itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's been used about a total of three times in the universe, but *autogenderphobic* would be recognized by people who are good enough at their Greek and Latin roots.  All twelve of them.

Comment: Googling this word results in single hit. Which points to your answer. Is this word in any dictionary?

Comment: @sig I think the point is there really isn't a common English word for this

Comment: People who are good at their Latin roots would immediately realise that two out of the three roots in _autogenderphobic_ are Greek, not Latin…

Answer (score 0):

*Gynophobe* (or *gynephobe*) means 'someone who fears, hates or has contempt for women' (see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gynophobe ).

Can also be *gyn(a)ecophobe* (see http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gynaecophobia ).

I don't believe there's a specific standard term for woman-on-woman hatred or someone who perpetrates it.